# CORS error when connecting local React frontend to local Spring Boot middleware application

Tags: java, reactjs, rest, spring-boot, cors

I am working on a frontend application in React that connects to a middleware service written in Spring boot. 
I am attempting to call an endpoint from the front end as follows:

```
return axios.post('http://localhost:8085/workshop/client/createClient', {username})
.then((response) => {
  console.log('Success')
})
.catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

Whenever I make the request in my browser I get the following errors:

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:8085/workshop/client/createClient 401 ()

Failed to load http://localhost:8085/workshop/client/createClient: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401.
```

As far as I understand, this is because the preflight request is being blocked by my middleware application.
Having read a bit online about enabling this, I have added a CorsFilter to my spring boot application:

```
@Slf4j
public class CORSFilter implements Filter {
  private static final String ONE_HOUR = "3600";

  @Override
  public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
  }

  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", ONE_HOUR);
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With,Origin,Content-Type, Accept, x-device-user-agent, Content-Type");

    if (req instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
       HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) req;
       if (httpServletRequest.getHeader(HttpHeaders.ORIGIN) != null
          && httpServletRequest.getMethod().equals(HttpMethod.OPTIONS.name())
          && httpServletRequest.getHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD) != null) {
          log.debug("Received an OPTIONS pre-flight request.");
          return;
       }
    }
    chain.doFilter(req, res);
  }

  @Override
  public void destroy() {
  }
}
```

And

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfiguration {

 @Bean
 public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
   FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
   filterRegistrationBean.setFilter(new CORSFilter());
   filterRegistrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");
   filterRegistrationBean.setOrder(0);
   return filterRegistrationBean;
 }
}
```

Here is an example of the endpoint:

```
 @PostMapping("/createClient")
 public ResponseEntity<?> createClient(@RequestBody CreateClientDto clientDto) {
    try {
     ...
     return new ResponseEntity<>(responseBody, OK);
    } catch (Exception e ...) {}
  }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

**Update:** I had the url slightly wrong for the request (hence the 404). I have updated the error message. I still seem to be having CORS issues.

These are the response headers that I can see in the dev tools:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:access-control-allow-credentials, access-control-allow-methods, access-control-allow-origin, allow, content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:3000
Allow:GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS, PATCH
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Length:0
Date:Thu, 01 Mar 2018 14:06:38 GMT
Expires:0
Pragma:no-cache
Strict-Transport-Security:max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
Vary:Origin
WWW-Authenticate:Basic realm="Spring"
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:DENY
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
```

And the request headers:

```
OPTIONS /workshop/client/createClient HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8085
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://localhost:3000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_3) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: access-control-allow-credentials,access-control-allow-methods,access-control-allow-origin,allow,content-type
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,da;q=0.7
```

Comment: The 404 seems to indicate that the URL `http://localhost:8085/createClient` is not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be resolved. I was missing the Accept request header (thanks @Anadi Sharma), and I also had the spring-boot-starter-security as a dependency, which seemed to be returning unauthorised. I also didn't need the CorsFilter, in the end I just used the @CrossOrigin annotation on the endpoint.

Comment: what do you mean by Accept request Header please.

Comment: explain more please or add the updated code.

Comment: can you please explain with updated codes, how did you solve ?

Answer (score 11):

I also had this issue, but allow me to give a straight forward answer in a simpler communication manner.

First and foremost, you have to tell your server (Spring boot java), about the client (Reactjs ) **URL**.

For example, most of the times spring boot uses `http://localhost:8080` and Reactjs `uses http://localhost:3000`.

So you have to navigate to the controller in Spring boot java and allow the **URL** of Reactjs to be given the permission for accessibility in the server (Spring boot). This will help you get rid of the **CORS** issue.

How do we do this in Spring boot? simply we add the `@CrossOrigin` annotation specifying the Reactjs **URL** link as below:

For example :

```
    @GetMapping("/orphans")
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
    Iterable<Student> read() {
        return studentService.findAll();
    }
```

The method above is to list all the orphans, so I gave Reactjs **URL** link permission then I got rid of the **CORS** issue.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 7):

### Controller.java

Refer to the below sample code to resolve this issue.

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
@RequestMapping(value="/sample", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")

public Student getStudent(){
}
```

Answer (score 6):

add below line of code in fetch

```
  export function getData(endpoint = '/', request = {}) {
    let url = endpoint;
    let req = Object.assign(
      {
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        },
      },
      request
    );
    console.log('url,req', url, req);
    return fetch(url, req).then(handleResponse).catch(handleErrors);
  }
```

And Add below line below Rest Controller class

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")
class TestController{}
```

hope this would helpful :)

Comment: @CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*") this is worked for me thank you

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin is a response header, not a request header

Answer (score 2):

This is a standard CORS issue, this basically means that user agent i.e. `http://localhost:3000` doesn't have permissions to access resources at `http://localhost:8085`. You can learn more about it at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS.

Your request headers should exactly map to server rules. Keeping any parameter as `*` won't work.

For e.g., if your request header has following:

```
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: <your custom headers>
```

Then, server rules show map your request header:

```
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET, PUT, DELETE, POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: <your custom headers>
```

Let me know if it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately I am still seeing the same issue. Am I missing a header for the request or the response? I have updated the question with the headers that I can see in the dev tools

Comment: Sorry for replying late to your comment, I have been busy for a couple of days. With your update on your question, I can see that your request headers doesn't match with the server rules. For e.g., `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` doesn't match with `Access-Control-Allow-Header`. The rules set at server and sent in your request headers must be exactly the same

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by adding bean configuration in server side (spring boot app) to allow origins.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer configure() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry reg) {
                reg.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*");
            }
        };
    }

}
```